# PyQt5 slow load label

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm writing an interface with PyQt5 and there is a QLineEdit for the user to enter a license key. When I set `.setInputMask("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX")`, it loaded very slowly and I didn't like the thick cursor. Therefore, I decided to create my own custom QLineEdit and validator. Just as I was about to start, I noticed that if you set the last character of the QLineEdit to a blank space, it loads very slowly. Using a non-breaking space instead of a space solves the issue, but it doesn't sit well with me. How can I solve this, or is there a way to make the cursor thin for this input mask, as far as I researched on the internet, it doesn't exist?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QWidget()

    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
    lineedit = QLineEdit("    -    -    -   \u00A0") # Fast but dosen't sit well with me

    lineedit1 = QLineEdit()
    lineedit1.setInputMask("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX")  # Thick cursor and slow load

    lineedit2 = QLineEdit("    -    -    -    ")  # Slow load

    layout.addWidget(lineedit)
    layout.addWidget(lineedit1)
    layout.addWidget(lineedit2)

    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems that if there is only one element, it arrives late, so it's not that important after all. Is there a way to solve the thick cursor?"

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please notify us whenever you update your question, we cannot follow *all* posts. That said, it's not clear what you mean by "slow load". Can you please clarify that?